# How to send multple requests in an loop?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make an automate project like send requests -> parse data - > connect to DB -> make a report via pandas.

I was almost done, but recently discovered a bug that my loop sends only the 1st method.

As you can see, I'm reading an .xml file and sending it as a body for request.

My version is that 2nd .xml is way too big, like 900 strings and about 8Kb, meanwhile the first .xml is about 20 string and 1kb.

Is there a way to fix it?

```
cargoType = input('Enter a cargo type (CargoRedirection): ')
cargoGuid = input('Enter a cargoGuid: ')
methods = ['method1', 'method2'] # methods here are coming from filenames in a folder ./methods

for method in methods:
    with open('./methods/' + str(cargoType) + '/' + str(method) + '.xml', 'rb') as methodBody:
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
            'Queue': 'Queue1',
            'Message-Type': str(method),
            'Branch': 'Branch1'
        }
        print(method)
        r = requests.post('url',
                          data=methodBody,
                          headers=headers)
    print(str(method) + 'was sent')
```

Comment: The code demonstrated would operate first on `method1` and then on `method2`.  If you're _not_ seeing that, then you haven't posted all of the code you're using, because there's no indication from the provided code that you would only process the first method in your list.  Did you omit a `return` statement in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

You should send the file content, not the file handle.

Your example is missing `.read()`

Try:

```
r = requests.post('url',
                  data=methodBody.read(),
                  headers=headers)
```

Comment: The problem was in encoding, it sent 1251 for utf-8
But I also think, that 576i helped me.
Thanks a lot!